# Select top unique record from duplicate record and then shuffle and show rest of the duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql

I have the requirement to show first top company_name unique records out of duplicate values and then shuffle rest of the data.
My table is something like this:

```
id  com_id  company_name    company_id
1   1          mufti            1
2   1          mufti            1
3   1          mufti            1
4   2          fcuk             2
5   2          fcuk             2
6   2          fcuk             2
7   3          denim            3
8   3          denim            3
9   3          denim            3
```

I tried with the below mentioned query and i am able to fetch the first top unique records but order by rand is not showing random data or is there any possible way to shuffle rest of the record using other then rand().

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_data AS td 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                   FROM product_data AS t 
                   WHERE t.company_id=td.company_id 
                     AND t.id=td.id- 1 )  
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM `product_data` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT id 
                   FROM product_data AS td 
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT `id` 
                                      FROM product_data AS t 
                                      WHERE t.company_id=td.company_id
                                      AND t.id=td.id- 1 ) 
                   ORDER BY id,RAND())
```

Output:

```
id  com_id  company_name    company_id
1   1            mufti         1
4   2            fcuk          2
7   3            denim         3
2   1            mufti         1
3   1            mufti         1
5   2            fcuk          2
6   2            fcuk          2
8   3            denim         3
9   3            denim         3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT id, com_id, company_name, company_id, rand
FROM ( SELECT *, (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS rand
FROM product_data AS td
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                   FROM product_data AS t 
                   WHERE t.company_id=td.company_id 
                     AND t.id=td.id- 1 ) 
UNION ALL
SELECT *, ROUND(RAND() * 10, 2) + 3 AS rand
FROM product_data
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                   FROM product_data AS td 
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id
                                      FROM product_data AS t 
                                      WHERE t.company_id=td.company_id
                                      AND t.id = td.id - 1 ) 
                                    )
ORDER BY rand ) AS temp
```

I added a rand column, which is a progressive number for the unique elements that must be at the first places, and a random number for the others.

Comment: This will gives me the desired output but when it comes to large records it will take too much time to execute.:(